# JQuery - Focus and Blur on textfield don't work

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, focus, blur

So, I'm serious confused here.
I have a `textfield`, which is used for Searching, and in that `textfield`, theres a default text(Search here).

I've added a `focus` and `blur` so when i `focus` on the `textfield`, the default text dispersers. And on `blur`, it comes back. But it's not working, even tho its working on the test i made first.

**Hers the JS:**

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script> 
<link href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script>
var data = [
        {"label" : "NAME | MAIL | NR."},
        {"label" : "NAME | MAIL | NR."}

        ];

$(function() {

    $('#search_bar').autocomplete(
    {
        source:data
    });
});


</script>

<script>

var default_value = "Search Here";

$(".ringenven").focus(function() {
    if($(".ringenven").val() == default_value)
    {
        $("ringenven").val("");
    }
});

$(".ringenven").blur(function() {
    if($(".ringenven").val() == "")
    {
        $(".ringenven").val(default_value);
    }
});

</script>
```

**Heres the textbox:**

```
<input class="ringenven" id="search_bar" style="MARGIN-TOP: 35px; MARGIN-LEFT: 10px; WIDTH: 300px; HEIGHT: 22px" type="text" size="9" value="Search Here" name="search_bar" />
```

Comment: why don't you just use the placeholder attribute

Comment: Damn... Didn't think of that ... Feel like the biggest idiot right now -.-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why don't you just use the placeholder attribute – @hyxnat

-Ty for kicking me in the head ;)

Answer (score 0):

on the focus within the condition body, you have forgotten the class selector.

use

```
$(".ringenven").val("");
```

instead of

```
$("ringenven").val("");
```

Comment: Yea saw that to right after the post, but that didn't fix it :(